# Internet Explorer do not open link(or redirect)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, redirect, hyperlink

In my website, there is a link :

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/control_panel/upload_img">Upload Image</a>
```

When I opened site any browser except Internet Explorer, there is no problem. When you click, you go to upload page.

But interesting thing is, when I open site in Internet Explorer 9 or 8, and click link, it goes to (or redirects to) my main page, not upload page.

I manually writes in address bar like :

```
www.mywebsite.com/control_panel/upload_img
```

It agains goes to main page.

What is the problem. Is this problem from me or Internet Explorer?

Comment: the link is ok check javascripts an jquery codes for problem

Comment: Can you provide direct link to your website? It's hard to help just with this description of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me this might be a cache problem: for some reason your main page has been cached/associated for the url you've provided.

You may want to clear your browser's cache and try loading this url again. If you stll get the same result, then the problem is likely to be different. In that case I have no idea what it could be.